# Сохранить расписание работы компании в MySQL

Tags: mysql, highload

Здравствуйте. Проектируется Hi-load БД.
Опыта в этом нет.
Сейчас расписания хранятся в отдельной таблице: company_id, day, hour.
Предлагается внести их в поле таблицы компаний в виде 168 бит (24*7).
Быстрее ли это будет работать? Какой тип данных выбрать?

Comment: Это зависит от того, что вы с этими данными делаете дальше. Если у вас запросы типа "найти компании работающие в выходные" то полный перебор таблицы для проверки этого битового поля вам гарантирован. индексы не спасут. А если просто показать на экране для уже выбранной компании то сойдет. А существующую сейчас таблицу в любом случае переделать надо. ну не работают компании в 13, 15, 18 работаем, в 14, 16, 17 нет. Уж лучше интервалы хранить. Кстати перерыв на обед с 13:15 до 14 или с 13:30 до 14:30 распространенное явление и описать его ни вашим текущим подходом, ни битовым полем невозможно

Comment: Какие именно проблемы вы имеете с текущей схемой? на каких операциях? каких операций у вас больше или какие важнее по скорости? сколько у вас компаний в базе? работа с расписанием ведется по одной компании или по многим сразу? вы уверены, что вам всегда будет достаточно хранить расписание с точностью 24*7? т.е. не могут начаться с пол-часа, нет особого расписания в праздники и предпраздничные дни?

Comment: при чем тут нагруженные системы?

Comment: Нужно определять, работает ли компания в данный момент. Т.е. в принципе это поле можно закэшировать и использовать битовые операции для проверки.

Answer (score 0):

- company_id,
- dateA - начало рабочего интервала
- dateB - конец рабочего интервала

Так можно указать любые примочки с обедами 13:30 и концом рабочего дня в пятницу в 16:45, вместо обычных 17:00.

А вообще при планировании хранения данных, нужно знать, какие будут запросы в будущем. Для чего храним данные? Что от них хотим получить?

Ваше уточнение, как будут использоваться данные, поможет нам точнее дать ответ.